# Stabilize hovercraft rigidbody upright using torque

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently creating a game involving a hover-bike. when the bike collides with something , it's angles change naturally. I wish to create some sort of way for it to tend back to 0. Here's what I've tried:

```
if (hoverbike.rotation.x != 0 || hoverbike.rotation.z != 0)
        {
            hoverbike.AddTorque(x: Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(hoverbike.rotation.x, 0, 0.01f), y: hoverbike.rotation.y, z: Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(hoverbike.rotation.z, 0, 0.01f));
        }

        transform.Rotate(0.0f, -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 0.5f, 0.0f);
```

It's hard to explain what it's doing because I don't understand what it's doing, it just seems to spin out.
Here's the rest of my code if interested: https://pastebin.com/kzMDQMVF, it's a mess but I'm still learning how to use Unity.

Oh and angle y shouldn't tend to 0 because that's the horizontal angle.

Comment: Please don't use quaternion components

Comment: What do I do instead?

Comment: See my answer for a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine the quaternion that would rotate the hovercraft from its current up to world up using [`Quaternion.FromToRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html):

```
Rigidbody hoverRB; // hovercraft's rigidbody

Quaternion deltaQuat = Quaternion.FromToRotation(hoverRB.transform.up, Vector3.up);
```

Then use [`Quaternion.ToAngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html) to convert that to an angle & axis:

```
Vector3 axis;
float angle
deltaQuat.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);
```

Then, cancel out some of any existing rotational velocity so that you'll eventually reach the goal:

```
float dampenFactor = 0.8f; // this value requires tuning
hoverRB.AddTorque(-hoverRB.angularVelocity * dampenFactor, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

And then apply some torque along the axis we found before, scaled by how much angle remains:

```
float adjustFactor = 0.5f; // this value requires tuning
hoverRB.AddTorque(axis.normalized * angle * adjustFactor, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

Any conversion between radians Rigidbody uses and degrees of `ToAngleAxis` is redundant with the `float` constants, so don't worry too much about it.

Make sure this is all being done in `FixedUpdate` (or a function called/running in `FixedUpdate` time) due to how the torque's direction will likely need to change from one physics step to another. So, altogether:

```
Rigidbody hoverRB; // hovercraft's rigidbody

...

void FixedUpdate() 
{    
    Quaternion deltaQuat = Quaternion.FromToRotation(hoverRB.transform.up, Vector3.up);

    Vector3 axis;
    float angle
    deltaQuat.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);

    float dampenFactor = 0.8f; // this value requires tuning
    hoverRB.AddTorque(-hoverRB.angularVelocity * dampenFactor, ForceMode.Acceleration);

    float adjustFactor = 0.5f; // this value requires tuning
    hoverRB.AddTorque(axis.normalized * angle * adjustFactor, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

Comment: @KatalystPrime Great! Happy to hear it worked first try! Out of curiosity, what `float` factors did you end up using? I'd like to edit practical values into my answer if possible :)

Comment: I haven't fine tuned them too precisely as of yet, but 0.8 seems like a good dampening factor so far (to me), but I haven't nailed down adjustment factor yet. currently using the default of 0.5 until I can nail it down further.