# Stuck Implementing A Way To Rotate A Rigidbody Towards A Point With Rigidbody.AddTorque

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

So I am kinda stuck on what to do now because as I said I am trying to use [Rigidbody.AddTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) to rotate a rigid body towards a certain point, which I was going to use to align a player with a gravitational pull so they can be upright. I have got the input part of the code, I just don't have a way to rotate the player to align with it, without violating the laws of physics with [Quaternion.FromToRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) and messing with my character controller too, which I am trying to make entirely physics based rotation wise too to avoid any other problems.

I have experimented with a couple of methods, first I tried adapting my character controller code which used [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to move the player and also dampening unwanted movements, as [Rigidbody.AddTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) is basically Rigidbody.AddForce but for rotations, however, it was too weak and just flopping around when I tried it, here's the code for the character controller for calculating the force needed for one axes:

```
if(projected_speed.x*speed == relative_v.x)
{
applied_speed.x = 0f;
}
else if(Mathf.Sign(projected_speed.x)== -1)
{
applied_speed.x = relative_v.x - Mathf.Abs(projected_speed.x*speed);
}
else if (Mathf.Sign(projected_speed.x) == 1)
{
applied_speed.x = projected_speed.x*speed - relative_v.x;
}
```

Where projected_speed is the speed the controller wants to be at,relative_v is the relative velocity, and applied_speed is the speed that will be actually applied in [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).
Anyways so maybe I didn't use enough force, as the player is under a gravitational pull, but that would have probably made it flip out or something, anyways so the second thing I tried was a [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller), and I managed to find a page which explains it pretty well, sadly don't have the link anymore, but when I tried this because you have to tune it, I was stuck doing it, and it just wasn't able to do anything and was just rolling around the floor and sometimes spinning, probably as it couldn't cope with gravity, so that didn't work, so does anyone know how I could finally do this and make my character able to right themselves according to gravity?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58420316/1092820) help?

Comment: Thanks, much more simpler than a PID controller, wish that came up,would have made my life so much easier. Again thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stabilize hovercraft rigidbody upright using torque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419942/stabilize-hovercraft-rigidbody-upright-using-torque)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not indicating that my issue is solved, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419942/stabilize-hovercraft-rigidbody-upright-using-torque/58420316#58420316) for the answer, credit to Ruzihm.