# Cant Balance A motor bike In unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to balance a motorbike with unity physics. We can balance balance bike by freezing rotation on z axis but doesnot seem good .So far i tried this .This method balances bike for few second but some reason bike start jumping in air or sometime flips over .I am open to any suggestions.I have made some 2d non physics games but unity physics is new to me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35zjP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTmNQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hqFK.png)

Comment: Sorry but stackoverflow isn't intended to solve game logic issues. Perhaps this is appropriate for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Also, please copy/paste your code instead of using image links as it's much more difficult to follow.

If you have a specific syntax error or technical issue that is reproducible then please update with details. Thank you

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If mine was helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) to give me some reputation points and help others browsing the search panel that there is a helpful answer here.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would stop changing the bike's center of mass.

Then, I would use the bike's up to calculate a torque to apply. Explanation in comments:

```
​float adjustFactor = 0.5f; // this value requires tuning

// physics actions should occur in FixedUpdate in most cases
void FixedUpdate()
{    
    // project the bike's local up to the plane perpendicular to the bike's forward
    Vector3 projectedUp = transform.up - Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, _transform.up);

    // find the angle from that projection to global up, around bike forward
    float upOffset = Vector3.SignedAngle(projectedUp, Vector3.up, transform.forward);

    // use angle difference to calculate an adjustment 
    float adjustment = upOffset * adjustFactor;

    // maybe do something else like adjustment = log(adjustment) or adjustment^2 
    //   to change easing of adjustment force. Requires some trial and error 
    //   and further tuning of adjustFactor.

    // Apply adjustment as vector around rb's forward
    _rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(0f, 0f, adjustment));
}
```

Related answer: [Stabilize hovercraft rigidbody upright using torque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58420316/1092820)